# Postgresql Database Replicate Using Docker-Compose File

Tags: database, postgresql, replication, database-replication, postgresql-13

I want to setup db replicate using docker-compose file for my company.
Does anyone have any solution for this! please kindly help me or provide some tibs.

Thank in advance

I want two database from DR and DC replicate to enhance my db performance.

Comment: Try googling "postgresql replication docker" for loads of guides.

Comment: Thanks  , but I have try as mush as possible and still resolve this.
Richard Huxton

Comment: Then add to your question what you've done and what happened

Comment: James Z
I am stating new with db replicate using docker-compose files, then I really need help from everyone to guide me with this case no matter provide me with the link or documentation.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Please check out this FAQ post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3470545